# Shortcut to insert / paste email address?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Is there a way to setup a shortcut to insert my email address when typing?

About once a day I need to type my email address on some login form or order page. It would be really nice to have a kind of paste function that inserts my email address.

Of course this is also a feature request: Long (context) tap while typing - cut/copy/paste/select menu pops up -> in that menu I would like to have an additional item: "Insert email address". Even better: Allow me to define additional "paste items".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Built in to the operating system is text replacements, so if you open Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Text Replacement you can add your own text replacement shortcuts. For example, you might add "e@" and have it expand to your full email address, such as "email@domain.com". It will automatically expand when tabbing away from a field or hitting the space key on your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I recommend using `@@` because there's no time when that comes up naturally; using something like `e@` may inadvertently replace text when typing something like `j.doe@domain.com`.

Comment: @joanwolk Good point, however, in my (very limited) testing, I haven't managed to have it replace e@ unless I absolutely write it on its own. It's definitely an issue with some other text replacement apps though.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! I just wish I'd known about this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the [Clips app](https://www.macstories.net/reviews/clips-review-actionable-clipboard-management-for-ios-8/) provides what you're looking for. It's basically a clipboard manager, which comes with a custom keyboard extension that lets you paste copied texts into text fields. It's a [free app available in the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/id917638056?mt=8&at=11l4LG&ct=clipsweb).

[image]